# MS SQL. Парсинг многомерного xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, xmlparser

Есть такой вот файлик:

```
<ROOT>
  <Customers>
    <Customer CustomerName="Arshad Ali" CustomerID="C001">
      <Orders>
        <Order OrderDate="2012-07-04T00:00:00" OrderID="10248">
          <OrderDetail Quantity="5" ProductID="10" />
          <OrderDetail Quantity="12" ProductID="11" />
          <OrderDetail Quantity="10" ProductID="42" />
        </Order>
      </Orders>
      <Address> Address line 1, 2, 3</Address>
    </Customer>
    <Customer CustomerName="Paul Henriot" CustomerID="C002">
      <Orders>
        <Order OrderDate="2011-07-04T00:00:00" OrderID="10245">
          <OrderDetail Quantity="12" ProductID="11" />
          <OrderDetail Quantity="10" ProductID="42" />
        </Order>
      </Orders>
      <Address> Address line 5, 6, 7</Address>
    </Customer>
    <Customer CustomerName="Carlos Gonzlez" CustomerID="C003">
      <Orders>
        <Order OrderDate="2012-08-16T00:00:00" OrderID="10283">
          <OrderDetail Quantity="3" ProductID="72" />
        </Order>
      </Orders>
      <Address> Address line 1, 4, 5</Address>
    </Customer>
  </Customers>
</ROOT>
```

Пытаюсь его прочитать и распарсить:

```
DECLARE
@xml AS XML;

WITH XMLwithOpenXML AS
( 
    SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() AS CurDate 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\...\my.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
)

SELECT @xml = BulkColumn FROM XMLwithOpenXML;

SELECT 
    x.value('./Customer[1]/@CustomerName[1]', 'nvarchar(250)') AS CustomerName,
    x.value('./Customer[1]/@CustomerID[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') AS CustomerID,
    x.value('./Customer[1]/Orders[1]/Order[1]/@OrderDate[1]', 'datetime') AS OrderDate,
    x.value('./Customer[1]/Orders[1]/Order[1]/@OrderID[1]', 'int') AS OrderID,
    x.value('./Customer[1]/Address[1]', 'nvarchar(250)') AS Address
FROM @xml.nodes('ROOT/Customers') x (x)
```

Получаю информацию только из первой ноды, по первому покупателю, как сделать так чтобы и остальные тоже парсились?

```
CustomerName  | CustomerID | OrderDate              | OrderID | Address  
Arshad Ali    |   C001     |2012-07-04 00:00:00.000 | 10248   | Address line 1
```

Comment: Если узел имеет множество вложенных узлов, то используйте nodes в CROSS APPLY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это прямо не ответ на ваш вопрос, но я показываю идею:

```
declare @TMP Table (XDocument XML)


INSERT INTO @TMP VALUES ('
<root>
    <TableRow>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Data>1</Data>
        <Data>2</Data>
        <Data>3</Data>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Data>4</Data>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <Data>5</Data>
        <Data>6</Data>
    </TableRow>
</root>
')


select tr.tc.value('(ID)[1]','int') as ID,d.dc.value('(.)[1]','int') as Data from @TMP
CROSS APPLY XDocument.nodes('root/TableRow') tr(tc)
CROSS APPLY tr.tc.nodes('./Data')  d(dc)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ключевой особенностью тут является `CROSS APPLY` и `nodes`, который нужно применять на элементах, которых более 1.

А еще можно на C# сделать SQL CLR и решить задачу пару строчками кода, выполнив десериализацию XML в класс, а потом возвратить табличное представление.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался